# Simpler R code for adding value column to dataframe based on ID column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset A and a summary dataset B.

```
A<-data.frame(ID=rep(c(1,2),times=c(3,2)))
A

ID
1
1
1 
2
2

B<-data.frame(ID=c(1,2),value=c(14,15))
B

ID value
 1 14
 2 15
```

I want to add a column in dataset A that has the values in B repeated for each ID, like this:

```
ID value
 1 14
 1 14
 1 14
 2 15
 2 15
```

So far, I've been achieving this using this code:

```
library(dplyr)
count<-A %>% group_by(ID)%>% tally()
n<-A$n
val<-rep(B$value,times=n)
A$value<-val
```

But I'm sure there's an easier way. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the simple `left_join` from `dplyr` instead of `rep`licating by 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(A, B)
```

-output

```
#   ID value
#1  1    14
#2  1    14
#3  1    14
#4  2    15
#5  2    15
```

---

Or with `match`

```
A %>% 
     mutate(value = B$value[match(ID, B$ID)])
```

-output

```
#   ID value
#1  1    14
#2  1    14
#3  1    14
#4  2    15
#5  2    15
```

---

Or using a join `on` with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)[B, value := value, on = .(ID)]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
A$value <- with(A, B$value[match(ID, B$ID)])
```

---

Or another simple option in `base R` is `merge`

```
merge(A, B, by = 'ID', all.x = TRUE)
```

-output

```
#   ID value
#1  1    14
#2  1    14
#3  1    14
#4  2    15
#5  2    15
```

Answer (score 2):

One simply way to do what you want is using `base R` match which behaves similarly to known look up functions:

```
#Data
A<-data.frame(ID=rep(c(1,2),times=c(3,2)))
B<-data.frame(ID=c(1,2),value=c(14,15))
#Add
A$value <- B[match(A$ID,B$ID),"value"]
```

Output:

```
A
  ID value
1  1    14
2  1    14
3  1    14
4  2    15
5  2    15
```